# Add PersistentCollection to an object in fixture

Tags: symfony, fixtures, symfony5

I'm trying to create a new fixture for creating a user.

This is the fixture :

```
class UserFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    private ManagerRegistry $_managerRegistry;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $this->_managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $groups = $manager->getRepository(Group::class)->findAll(); // This return an array of object. I want a PersistentCollection
        $company = $manager->getRepository(Company::class)->findOneBy(['company_name' => 'HANFF - Global Health Solution']);
        $user = new User();
        $user->setLogin("TEST_TEST")
             ->setName("TEST_Name")
             ->setFirstName("TEST_Firstname")
             ->setPassword("test")
             ->setEmail("TEST@hanff.lu");
        $user->setCompany($company);
        $user->setGroups($groups); // This don't work as it is just an array
        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
                CompanyFixture::class,
                GroupFixture::class
        );
    }
}
```

So I have already created the company and group which persist into my database.
And now I want to set to my new user the company and group which have been previously persisted by doctrine.

This work for my company as this is a single object.
But this is not working for my groups as it is typed as a PersistenCollection object and the `getRepository(Group::class)->findAll()` return an array of object *Group*.

Here the data contains in the $groups variable :

```
array:2 [
  0 => App\Entity\Group {#1039
    -code: "NAT"
    -label: "National"
  }
  1 => App\Entity\Group {#1044
    -code: "VET"
    -label: "VÃ©tÃ©rinaire"
  }
]
```

Here this is how I defined the groups into my User entity :

```
Class User{
  //    ...
  /**
     * @var PersistentCollection
     * Many user has many groups
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_group",
     *      joinColumns={@ORm\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_code", referencedColumnName="`code`")}
     *      )
     */
    private PersistentCollection $groups;

    public function getGroups(): PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }

    public function setGroups(PersistentCollection $groups): self
    {
        $this->groups = $groups;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addGroup($group): self
    {
        $this->getGroups()->add($group);
        return $this;
    }
    
    //     ...
}
```

I have read somewhere (can't remember where) that when you persist an object using doctrine, it can be accessed as a `PersistentCollection` but I can't figure how to do that (Except by creating a new `PersistentCollection()` which is certainly not the best manner to do it)?

I have tried setting `ArrayCollection` instead of `PersistentCollection`, but if I do that, doctrine yells at me when I try to persist my user object because it can't convert `ArrayCollection` to `PersistentCollection` (i guess).

Comment: you can't really easily fetch a PersistentCollection. However, you can circumvent by using your `addGroup` method (multiple times) instead of `setGroups` (once). I also find it funny, that you limit the given parameter of setGroups in a draconian manner, but with `addGroup` you can add null or a number, instead of type-hinting `Group` ;o)

Comment: You're right :) I haven't type-hinting Group in addGroup function ! I'm going to do it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the types of your properties, arguments and return values to the `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` interface. That's the interface `ArrayCollection` and `PersistentCollection` share. Don't forget to initialize your `groups` property to an `ArrayCollection` in the constructor. Otherwise calls to `addGroup` will fail on new user entities.

```
class User
{
  //    ...
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_group",
     *      joinColumns={@ORm\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_code", referencedColumnName="`code`")}
     *      )
     */
    private Collection $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // other initialization
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getGroups(): Collection
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }

    public function setGroups(Collection $groups): self
    {
        $this->groups = $groups;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addGroup($group): self
    {
        $this->getGroups()->add($group);
        return $this;
    }
    
    //     ...
}
```

Comment: It work perfectly ! Thank you very much.
Now i can set my groups like this in my fixtures :
```$user->setGroups(new ArrayCollection($groups));```